# Read parameters from config file (cfg plugin)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Im trying to use cfg plugin in jenkins to set some parameters to be used on all jobs(freestyle) inside a folder. Im not figuring out how to access the parameters on the config 'MyPropertiesConfig' from build general in each of the jobs. Im not using pipelines or DSL, actualy im using 'This project is parametrized' option and setting String Parameters manual on all jobs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you really want to use config file plugin? This can be achieves using credential plugin feeding it a file.

Comment: Correct alternatives are welcomed. will look at the credential plugin if that works or not. Thanks

Comment: explored the credentials plugin , but nothing sugests the possibility of passing parameters to jobs.